# Delete table row in AutoCAD using C#

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I'm writing a method to delete table rows in AutoCAD based on the value of the first column.

My code is:

```
public void deleteRow(String openingName)
{
    Transaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
    DocumentLock docLock = doc.LockDocument();

    using (tr)
    using (docLock)
    {
        if (!IsWriteEnabled || !IsReadEnabled) //Committing transactions closes everything for reading and writing so it must be reopened
        {
            tr.GetObject(this.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            tr.GetObject(this.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < NumRows; i++)
        {
             if (Cells[i, 0].GetTextString(FormatOption.ForExpression).Equals(openingName))
             {
                 DeleteRows(i, 1);
             }
        }

        GenerateLayout();
        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

However all it does is delete the values of the cells in the row, leaving an empty row.

How do I remove the row itself?

Comment: What is DeteRows method?

Comment: I thought it would delete the row at location i but all it does is empty the cells in that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to get rid of the GenerateLayout() call

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!IsWriteEnabled || !IsReadEnabled) 
        {
           var tb = tr.GetObject(this.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Table;
           // tr.GetObject(this.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
           tb.UpgradeOpen();
           for (int i = 1; i < NumRows; i++)
           {
               if (Cells[i, 0].GetTextString(FormatOption.ForExpression).Equals(openingName))
               {
                 tb.DeleteRows(i, 1);
                }
            }
            tb.DowngradeOpen();
         }
```

Comment: add some explanations